# How to automatically connect to phone using phone link

Tags: windows, android, sharing, microsoft, microsoft-phone-link

My windows 10 PC, phone link works as a startup app and also it works as background app. But it not connects to the android device automatically.

For each time to connect I will open the app and press reconnect. I want to connect it automatically to the device. what can I do?

Comment: I think that's how it is.  I have just complained about it to the developer.  You should too.

Comment: i was used that feature early a year but now its gone